# Flask URL encoding mis

Tags: python, html, encoding, flask

I'm using Python with Flask in my project, and I'm experiencing the following issue:

my data contains values like er%2fstudio_data_architect. I use flask to generate a page when I go to a page like http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/embarcadero/er%2fstudio_data_architect. In my code, I have

```
@app.route('/search/<vendor>/<product>')
```

One would expect this to work, as the / character from er/studio_data_architect is escaped with %2f, making it er%2fstudio_data_architect. But apparently, Flask still sees this as a / character, which results in my app.route being something like

```
@app.route('/search/<vendor>/<product>/<abundant code>')
```

Of course, creating these kinds of app.route's would be really ugly code.

Is there a better work-around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I've seen this issue before; IIRC it is not *Flask* that decodes the escaped slash, but your WSGI server. See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/900

Comment: I read your solution on the other problem, but I can't wrap my head around it... I tried something like:

`from werkzeug.routing import PathConverter
class EverythingConverter(PathConverter):
    regex = '.*?'
app.url_map.converters['product'] = EverythingConverter

@app.route('/search/<vendor>/<product>')`
, but it's not working

Comment: I found a solution to this problem, apparently making it <path:product> is all i had to do